# Displaying ads by using Admob

Tags: android, ads

I'm trying to insert an Ad into my new App but it doesn't load at all. The app loads perfectly and works as well, but the ad doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner spNivel; //Declarando o Spinner de nível.
Typeface fonte1;
private Button btnClicou;
private EditText campoBNow, campoLucro;

TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5;

//*
private AdView adView;
//*
```

...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-4388124170150808~1691605485");

    adView = findViewById(R.id.adTopo); //instancia o banner..
    AdRequest adR = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("657FA46182FBE07F2B99E75147AC2070").build(); //Gera uma propaganda no espaço criado...
    adView.loadAd(adR); //Carrega a propaganda de dentro do AdRequest.
```

...

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adTopo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

That's the code. Can anybody help?
The banner exists here --> https://ibb.co/cNoDr7 (image)

FULL XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fundopronto"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="269dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backfonte" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="269dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backfonte" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backfonte" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btCalcula"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backfonte" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backfonte" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtMenorBNow"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:typeface="serif"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewBNow" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewBNow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="@string/mBuyNow"
    android:textColor="@color/txtLaranja"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textosMenu"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtLucro"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:typeface="serif"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewLucro" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewLucro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="@string/lucroDes"
    android:textColor="@color/txtLaranja"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textosMenu"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewNivel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="@string/nivelC"
    android:textColor="@color/txtLaranja"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textosMenu"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinNivel"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btCalcula"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="@string/btnCalcula"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtResultado"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinNivel"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtResultado"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="192dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="192dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="192dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="192dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="393dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/valorTxt"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRisco"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textosMenu"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adTopo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It appears in my project, but doesn't when I run the app.

Comment: Here the banner exists... https://ibb.co/cNoDr7 (image)

Comment: Can you please post the complete XML of your layout?

Comment: @UdiIdan it's done man... Thank you.